# Chrome scaling scrollbars up

Tags: google-chrome

I just received a new laptop for work and the monitor display is 4k @ 3840 x 2160 with a 250% scale which is the recommended value. However most websites have their scrollbars scaled up 250% as well, which is hideous. However I've noticed some websites such as googles don't seem to have this issue. How are they telling the browser not to do this?

Examples: Stack Overflow has giant scroll bars

[image]

While googles website somehow avoids this.

[image]